# Converting a string in "key : value" form to list or dictionary and extract values

Tags: python, linux

I need to extract the free memory of a system by using the linux command

```
cat /proc/meminfo
```

The output is something like:

```
MemTotal:        1979676 kB
MemFree:          396244 kB
Buffers:          265048 kB
Cached:           629892 kB
SwapCached:           60 kB
Active:           503916 kB
Inactive:         770644 kB
Active(anon):     116564 kB
Inactive(anon):   369112 kB
Active(file):     387352 kB
Inactive(file):   401532 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:       2025468 kB
SwapFree:        2025276 kB
Dirty:               208 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:        379692 kB
Mapped:            76752 kB
Shmem:            106056 kB
Slab:             253328 kB
SReclaimable:     231816 kB
SUnreclaim:        21512 kB
KernelStack:        2720 kB
PageTables:        22152 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:     3015304 kB
Committed_AS:    2489860 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:      538576 kB
VmallocChunk:   34359176332 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:    210944 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:       38908 kB
DirectMap2M:     1988608 kB
```

Now, I'm interested in only the first 2 lines i.e, the parameters MemTotal and MemFree. I wrote the following code to extract the first 2 parameters :

```
mi_l=[]
mt_l=[]
mf_l=[]
mf=[]
mi_j=[]
mi_mt=[]
mi_mf=[]
t=0
for i in range(0,4):
    tn1.write("cat /proc/meminfo")
    tn1.write("\n")
    time.sleep(2)
    rd_buf = telnet.read_very_eager()
    mi=rd_buf.splitlines()[:3]
    print "splitlines :\n"+str(mi)
    for ln in mi:
        mi_l.append([int(p) for p in ln.split() if p.isdigit()])
print(mi_l)
for i in range(0,12):
    print(mi_l[i])
for i in range(4,12):
    if i%3!=0:
        mt_l.append(mi_l[i])
        avail_mem=mt_l[0]
        print(mt_l)
for i in range(0,6):
    if i%2!=0:
        mf_l.append(mt_l[i])
        print(mf_l)
for i in mf_l:
    t=t+i
print(t)
ram_free=t/3
print "Total Available Memory : "+str(avail_mem)+"Free RAM :"+str(ram_free)
```

As you can see, I'm trying to extract the *MemFree* parameter 3 times and take the average of those 3 values. But I get the error **unsupported operand types for '+' : 'int' and 'list'** which is when I realized that *mf_l* turns out to be a list within a list.
What would be the best way to get what I need? It would be helpful if someone suggests a tweak in the code or an alternative solution.

Comment: IIUC you are only interested in the first two lines right?

Comment: you can `flatten` the list by doing `mf_l = [ item for sublist in mf_l for item in sublist ]`.

Comment: In this example, what would be the 3 values you are trying to average?

Comment: @JulienSpronck : _MemFree_ parameter obtained thrice by looping 'cat /proc/meminfo'

Comment: Why build a list in `mi_l.append([int(p) for p in ln.split() if p.isdigit()])`
when really all you ever get is one element for that list? `mi_l.append([int(p) for p in ln.split() if p.isdigit()].pop())` should get you the right result if I understood correctly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @jsfan: tried that too. It says **IndexError: pop from empty list**.

Comment: @skrowten_hermit: Sounds like you sometimes get nothing. do you ever get empty lists? You could jut catch that exception and either ignore it or do extra polls on telnet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without delving any deeper into your code, your line
    `mi_l.append([int(p) for p in ln.split() if p.isdigit()])`
is appending a list (from your list comprehension statement) to your mi_l list. That's why you're getting a list of lists. If you wanted a single flat list, you could change "append" to "extend".
Here's a working version of your code, greatly simplified:

    `import time
    input_file = '35474429-in.txt'
    tn1 = open('35474429-out.txt', 'w')
    iterations = 3
    mi_l=[]
    t = f = 0
    for i in range(iterations):
        tn1.write("cat /proc/meminfo\n")
        time.sleep(2)
        rd_buf = open(input_file, 'r').read() #telnet.read_very_eager()
        mi=rd_buf.splitlines()[:2] # [:3]
        tn1.write("splitlines : %s\n" % str(mi))
        for ln in mi:
            mi_l.extend([int(p) for p in ln.split() if p.isdigit()])
    print(mi_l)
    for i in range(0, len(mi_l), 2):
        print(mi_l[i], mi_l[i+1])
        t += mi_l[i]
        f += mi_l[i+1]
    ram_free = f / iterations
    ram_total = t / iterations
    results = "Average Available Memory : "+str(ram_total)+", Free RAM :"+str(ram_free)
    print(results)
    tn1.write(results)`
You can run the code by creating the input file named in the code and populating it with at least the first two lines of your sample input. It generates a sample output. A few things for you:
(1) Never hard code anything when you need the value in multiple places. It's better to make and use a single variable.
(2) "append" adds an item to a list. "extend" adds multiple items to a list.
(3) the `range` statement can take a 3rd argument as an incrementation value.
Good luck.

Comment: Woww. Thanks for pointing our the difference between 'append' and 'extend'. That is where my understanding lacked. The above solved my problem in  jiffy. :)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you can use `head -n 2 /proc/meminfo` instead of `cat /proc/meminfo` to get only the first two lines from `/proc/meminfo`.

And then you can extract the number from the second line and transfer it to a number as follows:

```
import os

mem_free = 0
for i in range(4):
    tn1.write("head -n 2 /proc/meminfo")
    tn1.write("\n")
    time.sleep(2)
    rd_buf = telnet.read_very_eager()
    mi=rd_buf.splitlines()[:3]
    mem_free += int(mi[2].split()[1])

mem_free /= 4.0
```

Comment: I appreciate your simplified solution of using 'head -n 2 /proc/meminfo' but I'm doing this over a telnet session to a remote system. Your solution would help only if the target system is the same workstation that you are working at. Right?

Comment: @skrowten_hermit can you paste what you get from `telnet.read_very_eager()`? `os.popen('head -n 2 /proc/meminfo').read()` gives you a string like `'MemTotal:       98996080 kB\nMemFree:         7492352 kB\n'`, so this solution works if your telnet returns the same string.

Comment: head -n 2 /proc/meminfo\n
MemTotal:         116712 kB\n
MemFree:           86368 kB\n
That's what I get. First line makes life a bit difficult.

Comment: @skrowten_hermit you mean a string like `head -n 2 /proc/meminfo MemTotal: 116712 kB MemFree: 86368 kB` with no `\n` in it?

Comment: that's right. first line is 'head -n 2 /proc/meminfo'

Comment: @skrowten_hermit I edited my answer. You can just pick the third line after splitlines() and then apply the same text processing part.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103803/discussion-between-ycflame-and-skrowten-hermit).

Answer (score 1):

I've parsed many files of this type. I do something a bit more generic so that it works across many files, so my example will drift a bit from yours. First, you can handle the telnet session differently - have the remote return a well-known string that tells you when the command is done. Then, just split the strings instead of doing complicated, non-obvious and error prone string indexing. I use a `dict` so that I can grab whatever data I want without worrying about the exact order where the data appears.

```
info = { 'MemTotal': [0]*4, 'MemFree': [0]*4}

# it will look one way when echoed, another when executed
send_sentinel = '"********" "end sentinel" "********"'
check_sentinel = '******** end sentinel ****'

do_wait = False

for i in range(4):
    # wait between samples after first time through loop
    if do_wait:
        time.sleep(2)
    do_wait = True

    # in case crud is in pipe
    tn1.read_very_eager()
    # send command plus echo when done
    tn1.write('cat /proc/meminfo;echo {}\n'.format(send_sentinel))
    # wait for sentinel... i think the next read skips \r in return
    tn1.read_until(check_sentinel)
    txt = tn1.read_until('\n')

    want = 2 # for early break
    for line in txt.split():
        try:
            # assume we got a good line
            name, kb = line.split()[:2]
            name = name [:-1] # key rid of colon
            if name in info:
                info[name] = int(kb)
                want -= 1
                if not want:
                    break # early break
        except ValueError:
            pass # not our line

mem_free = sum(info['MemFree'])/4

print('total {}, free {}'.format(info['Memtotal'][0], mem_free))
```